# Python: Converting Binary to Decimal

Tags: python-3.x, list, binary, type-conversion, decimal

What I'm currently doing is a implementation of Genetic Algorithms. I have written my Crossover and mutation methods and now i'm currently writing my Fitness method.

I need to convert my list of 0s and 1s to decimal values for calculating distance.

My current output that I'm working with are a list of integer values of 1s and 0s. (Example below):

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
<class 'list'>
```

I want to convert these numbers to their respected binary equivalent. 
I have tried converting the list to groups of 4 and then calling a binaryToDecimal function to convert the bits to decimal values. However, Im getting an error 'TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable'.
I have summarized my code and this is what it looks like so far.

```
def converting_binary_to_decimal(L):
    output = []
    for l in L:
        l = list(map(str, l))
        sub_output = []
        for j in range(0, len(l)-1, 4):
            sub_output.append(int(''.join(l[j:j+4]), 2))
        output.append(sub_output)
    return output

def chunks(L, n):
    for i in range(0, len(L), n):
        yield L[i:i+n]

def fitness(child):
    newList1=list(chunks(child[0], 4))
    newList2=list(chunks(child[1], 4)) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    myFitness = fitness(afterMU)
```

A sample output of what i want is:
[[0, 13, 6, 8, 12, 8, 10, 9, 15], [0, 8, 7, 0, 4, 4, 1, 8, 15]]

Comment: Questions asking for help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Please read [ask] and [edit] your post with a [mre] detailing your efforts and explain whats wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
def converting_binary_to_decimal(L):
    output = []
    for l in L:
        l = list(map(str, l))
        sub_output = []
        for j in range(0, len(l)-1, 4):
            sub_output.append(int(''.join(l[j:j+4]), 2))
        output.append(sub_output)
    return output


L = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]

converting_binary_to_decimal(L)
```

Comment: l = list(map(str, l))
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

Answer (score 0):

I think i figured it out.

```
 x=[0, 1, 1, 0]
        k = 4
        n = len(x)//k
        for i in range(n):
            y = x[i*k:(i+1)*k]
            y = [str(j) for j in y]
            y = ''.join(y)
            y = int(y,2)
            print(y)
```

Thank you.